# Bind a QAbstractListModel derived listmodel member of an object in QML as Q_PROPERTY

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick, qabstractlistmodel

I figured out how to expose and bind an instance of a QAbstractListModel derived listmodel to/in QML.

But what I really want to do is to expose an object to QML and bind a member which is a QAbstractListModel derived listmodel as Q_PROPERTY.

I've tried it this way:

```
class MyObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(MyListModel myListModel READ myListModel NOTIFY myListModelChanged)

    public:
        explicit MyObject(QObject *parent = 0);
        MyListModel *myListModel();

    signals:
        void myListModelChanged();

    public slots:

    private:
        MyListModel *m_myListModel;

};


MyObject::MyObject(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    m_myListModel = new MyListModel(this);
}

MyListModel *MyObject::myListModel()
{
    return m_myListModel;
}

class MyListModel : public QAbstractListModel {
    Q_OBJECT
//...   
//...
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication a(argc, argv);

    QQuickView *view = new QQuickView();
    MyObject *myObject = new MyObject();

    view->engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("myObject", myObject);    
    view->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("main.qml"));   
    view->show();

    return a.exec();
}

Rectangle {
    width: 200
    height: 200

//...
//...

    ListView {
        id: myListView
        anchors.fill: parent
        delegate: myDelegate
        model: myObject.myListModel
    }
}
```

But I'm getting an compile error:

> E:\Qt\Qt5\5.1.1\mingw48_32\include\QtCore\qglobal.h:946: error: 'QAbstractListModel& QAbstractListModel::operator=(const QAbstractListModel&)' is private
>        Class &operator=(const Class &) Q_DECL_EQ_DELETE;
>               ^

How is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

QObjects like QAbstractItemModels cannot be copied, you must use a pointer. I’d use:

```
Q_PROPERTY(MyListModel* myListModel READ myListModel CONSTANT)
```

As you don’t replace the model itself, just its content, you don’t need the myListModelChanged() signal and can mark it as `CONSTANT`.

Your getter already has the right type, although it should be const:

```
MyListModel *MyObject::myListModel() const
```